Confirmation on volatility of ViT loss when training using a Masked AutoEncoder
Hi I am training ViT (patch 16, 224, ImageNet Pretrained) backbone on satellite imagery (Million-AID dataset, ~900000 images of varying sizes) in Self-Supervised learning fashion using an Masked Auto Encoder (MAE). The loss I get during training is very volatile and wanted to confirm if anyone knows if this behavior is normal when training a ViT or when training ViT using MAE approach?

I have pasted the code here just in case I have made a mistake. I am using the lightly-ssl to ease up training an MAE.
# ==============================================================================
# MAE Imp0lementation : THE PAPER HAS TWO DIFFERENT SETTINGS FOR PRETRAINING & FINETUNING
# What the paper uses | Any changes that deviate from paper
# Backbone : VIT-L/16 | VIT-B/16
#   Decoder : depth - 8 blocks, Width - 512d
#   Encoder : w/o mask tokens
# Optimizer
#   linear lr scaling (cosine decay) : lr = base_lr x bs / 256, base_lr = 1.5e-3/1e-3, warmup = 40/5 epochs
#   AdamW : Beta1,2 = 0.9,0.95 / 0.9,0.999
# Batch Size : 4096/1024 | 1024/1024
# Loss func : MSE
# Masking : 75%
# Augmenntation : RandomResized Crop     
#   Crop Size : 224x224
# Fine tuning : 50 epochs vs Pretraining : 200 epochs
#   Note that these are for Vit-L
# ==============================================================================

mae_params = config["mae_params"]

class MaeBBViT(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, model_params:dict, backbone:VisionTransformer):
        """
        Inputs 
            - model_params: dictionary containing model parameters such as lr, batch_size
            - backbone : vit model with last layer removed 
        """
        super().__init__()

        # Saving hyperparameters
        hyper_dict = {}
        hyper_dict.update(mae_params)
        hyper_dict.update(model_params)
        self.save_hyperparameters(hyper_dict)

        self.model_params = model_params

        self.backbone = backbone # we will need this later

        self.mask_ratio = mae_params["mask_ratio"] # 0.75
        self.patch_size = backbone.patch_embed.patch_size[0] #(16,16) so index [0] returns 16
        self.masked_encoder = MaskedVisionTransformerTIMM(vit = backbone)
        self.sequence_length = self.masked_encoder.sequence_length #197
        self.decoder = MAEDecoderTIMM(
            num_patches = backbone.patch_embed.num_patches, #196
            patch_size = self.patch_size,#196
            embed_dim = backbone.embed_dim, #768
            decoder_embed_dim = mae_params["decoder_dim"], #512
            decoder_depth = mae_params["decoder_depth"], #8
            mlp_ratio = 4.0,
            proj_drop_rate = 0.0, # drop out rate in projection head
            attn_drop_rate = 0.0 # drop out rate in 
        )
        self.criterion = nn.MSELoss()

        self.apply_lr_scheduler = False if model_params["lr"] else True

    def forward_encoder(self, images, idx_keep = None):
        # shape returned from .encode = (bs, num_unmasked_patches, embed size)
        # What you pass here as images are actually just unamsked portion of the image only
        # So if 50/197 patches were left not masked you get the shape below (total 197 including cls) of which 50 is not masked
        return self.masked_encoder.encode(images = images, idx_keep = idx_keep) #(*,3,224,224) -> (*,50,768)

    def forward_decoder(self, x_encoded, idx_keep, idx_mask):
        # Build decoder input
        batch_size = x_encoded.shape[0]

        x_decode = self.decoder.embed(x_encoded) #(*,50,512) where 50 is number NOT makes patches, 512 is num dimension decalred above

        x_masked = repeat_token(
            self.decoder.mask_token,
            (batch_size, self.sequence_length)
        ) #(*,197,512) where 197 nuber of masked patches & 512 is the nub dimensions declared above

        x_masked = set_at_index(x_masked, idx_keep, x_decode.type_as(x_masked)) #(*,197,512)

        # decoder forward pass
        x_decoded = self.decoder.decode(x_masked) #(*,197,512) 

        # Predict pixel values for masked tokens
        x_pred = get_at_index(x_decoded, idx_mask) #(*,147,512)
        x_pred = self.decoder.predict(x_pred) #(*,147,768)

        return x_pred

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        X,y,f = batch 
        images = X[0] # (*,3, 224,224) There is only a single view but its within a list
        batch_size = images.shape[0]
        # These are unmasked and masked patches. Rememnber that there is 197 patches including ...
        # CLS token (14*14 + 1), 14 patches was obtained by 224/16 where each patch is 16 pixels in height and width 
        idx_keep, idx_mask = random_token_mask(
            size = (batch_size, self.sequence_length),
            mask_ratio = self.mask_ratio,
            device = images.device
        ) #(*,50),(*,147)
        x_encoded = self.forward_encoder(
            images = images, 
            idx_keep = idx_keep
        ) #(*,50,768) where 50 is the number of NOT maked patches
        x_pred = self.forward_decoder(
            x_encoded = x_encoded, 
            idx_keep = idx_keep, 
            idx_mask = idx_mask
        ) #(*,147,768) where 147 are the number of masked patches

        # get image patches for masked tokens
        patches = patchify(images, self.patch_size) #(*,196,768)
        # must adjust idx mask for missing class token
        target = get_at_index(patches, idx_mask - 1) #(*, 147, 768)

        self.loss = self.criterion(x_pred, target) #(,)
        return self.loss

    def on_train_epoch_end(self) -> None:
        self.log("training loss" , self.loss)

        if self.apply_lr_scheduler:
            self.log("current lr", self.scheduler.get_lr()[0])
        else:
            self.log("current lr", self.model_params["lr"])

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        if self.apply_lr_scheduler:
            optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(
                params= self.parameters(), 
                lr = mae_params["base_lr"] * self.model_params["eff_batch_size"] / 256, 
                weight_decay=mae_params["weight_decay"]
            )
            self.scheduler = LinearWarmupCosineAnnealingLR(
                optimizer = optimizer, 
                warmup_epochs=mae_params["warmup_epochs"], # Linearly rampup lr as then decay using cosine as indicated in paper
                max_epochs=self.model_params["epochs"], 
                warmup_start_lr=mae_params["base_lr"], # we linearly ramp up from 0 to base_lr which is indicated in the optimizer
                eta_min=mae_params["eta_min"] #* We keep eta_min at 0 as Dino Paper hasnt indicated a value
            )
            return [optimizer],[{"scheduler" : self.scheduler, "interval" : "epoch"}] 
        else:
            optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(
                params = self.parameters(), lr = self.model_params["lr"], weight_decay=mae_params["weight_decay"]
            )
            return optimizer


